# Генерация кода из диаграммы классов С++

Tags: case, visual-studio, c++, visio

Здравствуйте.

Необходимо осуществить объектно-ориентированное проектирование с использованием объектно-ориентированного CASE-средства, например «WithClass». О WithClass не нашел ничего, если кто знает, просветите, пожалуйста.

Узнал, что можно использовать MS Visio, там создал диаграмму классов.

Как импортировать ее в Visual Studio и сгенерировать код C++ для этой диаграммы? Нужно ли что-то доустанавливать к Visual Studio? Или как-то изменять настройки?

Спасибо.

Comment: Вроде Rational Rose обычно юзают для такого. По нему много литературы.

Comment: Rational используют только очень крутые компании, а так слишком избыточная система для мелких, средних проектов

Answer (score 2):

Пользуюсь [Software Ideas Modeler](http://www.softwareideas.net/), очень достойная программа, как раз подойдет для вашего вопроса.